# Mockito Inconsistent Verification of Call on Mocks

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Basically, Mockito is saying that a method isn't called when it was. However, it only says this sometimes. Most of the time the test succeeds, but about 15% of the time it doesn't while the method is consistently called.

Dependencies:

- IntelliJ 2020.2.2
- Gradle 6
- JUnit Jupiter 5.6.2
- Mockito 3.5.13

Example of my test classes:

```
public class TestMethods {

    public void basic(Player player) { print("basic"); }
    public void basicReq(Player player, String argument) { print("basicReq"); }
    public void basicOpt(Player player, @Optional String argument) { print("basicOpt"); }
    public void basicDef(Player player, @Optional("def") String argument) { print("basicDef"); }
    public void aliased(Player player) { print("aliased"); }

    ... More methods ...

    private static void print(String s) { // This is here to verify that Mockito is wrong
        System.out.println("called " + s);
        new RuntimeException().printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
public class InvocationClass {

    public void execute(...) {
        
        Object[] parameters = ...
        try {
            System.out.println("Invoking " + method.getName() + " Instance " + instance + " Params " +
                    Arrays.stream(parameters).map(String::valueOf).collect(toList()));
            generatedInvoker.invoke(instance, parameters);
            System.out.println("Invoked");
        } catch (UncheckedReflectiveOperationException e) {

            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof RuntimeException) {
                throw (RuntimeException) cause;
            }

            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class MethodTest {

    private TestMethods mock;
    private TestManager manager;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach() {
        manager = new TestManager();
        mock = spy(TestMethods.class);
        Map<Class<?>, Object> instances = getFieldValue(TestManager.class, manager, "instances");
        instances.put(TestMethods.class, manager);
        manager.register(Stream.of(TestMethods.class.getDeclaredMethods())
                .filter(method -> method.isAnnotationPresent(Command.class))
                .collect(toList()));
    }

    @Test
    public void testBasic() {
        Player player = mockPlayer();
        assertTrue(manager.execute(player, "basic"));
        verify(mock).basic(eq(player));
    }

    @Test
    public void testBasicRequired() {
        Player player = mockPlayer();
        assertTrue(manager.execute(player, "basic-req test"));
        verify(mock).basicReq(eq(player), eq("test"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testBasicOptional() {
        Player player = mockPlayer();
        assertTrue(manager.execute(player, "basic-opt"));
        assertTrue(manager.execute(player, "basic-opt test"));
        verify(mock).basicOpt(eq(player), isNull());
        verify(mock).basicOpt(eq(player), eq("test"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testBasicDefault() {
        Player player = mockPlayer();
        assertTrue(manager.execute(player, "basic-def"));
        assertTrue(manager.execute(player, "basic-def test"));
        verify(mock).basicDef(eq(player), eq("def"));
        verify(mock).basicDef(eq(player), eq("test"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAliases() {
        Player player = mockPlayer();
        assertTrue(manager.execute(player, "alias"));
        verify(mock).aliased(eq(player));
    }
}
```

When I run the tests it's inconsistent, but basically I get the following printed out:

```
Invoking basic Instance com.package.TestMethods$MockitoMock$1613761242@13392152 Params [Mock for Player, hashCode: -421702893]
called basic
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at com.package.TestMethods.print(TestMethods.java:71)
    at com.package.TestMethods.basic(TestMethods.java:17)
    at com.package.TestMethods$MockitoMock$1613761242.basic$accessor$T72Aqfcr(Unknown Source)
    at com.package.TestMethods$MockitoMock$1613761242$auxiliary$gidMNiyZ.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.RealMethod$FromCallable$1.call(RealMethod.java:40)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.RealMethod$FromBehavior.invoke(RealMethod.java:62)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.InterceptedInvocation.callRealMethod(InterceptedInvocation.java:141)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.answers.CallsRealMethods.answer(CallsRealMethods.java:44)
    at org.mockito.Answers.answer(Answers.java:98)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:106)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor$DispatcherDefaultingToRealMethod.interceptSuperCallable(MockMethodInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.package.TestMethods$MockitoMock$1613761242.basic(Unknown Source)
    at com.package.generated.TestMethods_basic1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.package.InvocationClass.handleExecute(InvocationClass.java:220)
    at com.package.Manager.lambda$execute$4(Manager.java:291)
    at com.package.Manager$$Lambda$338/0000000000000000.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Invoked



Wanted but not invoked:
TestMethods.basic(
    Mock for Player, hashCode: -421702893
);
-> at com.package.MethodTest.testBasic(MethodTest.java:80)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
TestMethods.basic(
    Mock for Player, hashCode: -421702893
);
-> at com.package.MethodTest.testBasic(MethodTest.java:80)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Meaning the method was called through the mock and all of the parameters were correct, but for some reason Mockito is saying that there were zero interactions with the mock.

Note that I'm using a spied instance, but I did change it to an interface at one point and the same thing occurred so it's not to do with the spy. Also, as I said above, each of these tests will succeed most of the time and then a few times fail for this reason.

Am I doing something wrong here? Has anyone else encountered this before?

Thanks for your time

Comment: The problem behind this kind of behavior could be that you call the method `TestMethods.basic()` on one `TestMethod` mock and verify the behavior on another `TestMethod` mock

Comment: It looks like that actually may be the case somehow despite each test having its own spied instance and completely new instance set. Going to try to figure this out. Thank you